# Get-ChildItem through Invoke-WMIMethod or WMI in general

Tags: powershell, wmi, remote-access, get-childitem

Is there a way to run `Get-ChildItem` on a remote computer using `Invoke-WMIMethod` or something similar? My use case is that I need to find every SID that exists in the `HKEY_USERS` hive.

The `HKEY_USERS` hive contains a list of SIDS like so: 
[image]

I want to be get a list of these **through WMI** on a remote computer, without knowing the SIDs ahead of time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`StdRegProv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393664(v=vs.85).aspx) registry provider WMI class:

```
$RemoteComputer = 'computer1.hostname.goes.here'
$RegProv = [wmiclass]"\\$RemoteComputer\ROOT\DEFAULT:StdRegProv"

# Magic number identifying the HKEY_USERS hive
$HKU = 2147483651

# Enumerate values under the root key, sNames property will hold key names
$Keys = $RegProv.EnumKey($HKU,'') |Select-Object -ExpandProperty sNames
```

And here, using the [`Invoke-WmiMethod` cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/invoke-wmimethod):

```
$RemoteComputer = 'computer1.hostname.goes.here'
$ClassPath = "\\$RemoteComputer\ROOT\DEFAULT:StdRegProv"
$HKU = 2147483651

$Keys = Invoke-WmiMethod -Path $ClassPath -Name EnumKey -ArgumentList 2147483651,'' |Select-Object -ExpandProperty sNames
```

Comment: Thank you Mathias, this works. Is there a way to do this using Invoke-WMIMethod, though? I would like to be consistent in my code.

Comment: Why don't I need to provide credentials? I want to access the contents of these `HKEY_USERS` hives soon, would a `-Credentials` flag solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an easier way to get what you are looking for:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_UserProfile -Filter "SID like 'S-1-5-21-*'" -ComputerName ExampleComputer | select SID
```

Comment: Would I need to provide credentials to access these values? What about values within `HKEY_Users`?

Comment: The account running this will need admin rights. Rather than retrieving the information from the registry, this is from a separate WMI provider. The values in `HKEY_Users` matches up with the user profiles on the computer. With some additional information, for example `localpath` which mostly aligns to username, which I saw you were looking for in another question.